# AWS App Runner auto scaling configuration for handling occassional spikes

Tags: amazon-web-services

We're serving `php:7.4-apache` image through AWS App Runner and wanna handle spikes of 40k~ or so requests. But we're running into `max queue length has been reached` error sometimes.

Here's our App Runner service info:

- Virtual CPU & memory: 1 vCPU & 2 GB
- Concurrency: 100
- Minimum size: 10
- Maximum size: 25

(we're using default `apache.conf` and `php.ini` settings on the image)

Here's how we're faring:

[image: a screenshot of the App Runner dashboard's metrics section]

As you can see, we responded with 4xx more than 3k times when the request count reached 37k. To prevent that, what should we change?

- Is the concurrency of 100 too high?
- Shall we optimize the apache and php configurations?

Comment: Max is already set to the max limit, so increasing that is no option. Selecting 2vCPU +4GB RAM could help, did you try that?